# After adding a link modifier in attributeText, the text in the range becomes invisible

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I’m trying to create links using NSAttributedString, but when I add a link to the text, they become invisible, underlined still visible, and if I click on the text, it will show my debug message,

```
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Sample text for test")
attributedText.addAttribute(.link, value: "some url", range: NSMakeRange(0, 5))
attributedText.addAttribute(.underlineStyle, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, 5))
attributedText.addAttribute(.foregroundColor,  value: UIColor.blue, range:NSMakeRange(0, 5))
attributedText.addAttribute(.underlineColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: NSMakeRange(0, 5))

myTextView.attributedText = attributedText
myTextView.delegate = self
myTextView.isEditable = false
myTextView.isSelectable = true
```

I have such results
http://prnt.sc/ojd06v

Comment: attributedText.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.black, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length)). You didn't set default textColor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `linkTextAttributes` of your TextView.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code example:

```
     let data = Data("My URL stringggg...".utf8)
     if let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
            let foundRange = (attributedString.string as NSString).range(of: "My URL")
            if foundRange.location != NSNotFound {
                attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: "url", range: foundRange)
            }
            myTextView.linkTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
            myTextView.attributedText = attributedString
        }
```

It works for me.